# Locally deploying a GCloud app with a custom Docker image

Tags: deployment, docker, gcloud

I have been deploying my app from a bash terminal using an app.yaml script and the command:
`gcloud app deploy app.yaml`

This runs a main.app script to set the environment from a custom made docker image. 
How can I deploy this locally only so that I can make small changes and see their effects before actually deploying which takes quite a while?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app locally, you should be able to do that outside of the docker container.  We actually place very few restrictions on the environment - largely you just need to make sure you're listening on port 8080.

However if you really want to test locally with docker - you can...

```
# generate the Dockerfile for your applications
gcloud beta app gen-config --custom

# build the docker container
docker build -t myapp .

# run the container
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myapp
```

From there, you should be able to hit http://localhost:8080 and see your app running.

Hope this helps!